# Unable to make sammy js route work with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I am building a SPA keeping this [article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html) as a starting point.
jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fjj7q/light/)

I am trying to convert this solution to use sammyjs based on this [article](http://www.softfinity.com/blog/an-simple-introduction-to-url-routing/)
jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/28WJF/light/)

I came with my mashup fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jarajesh/Nch5m/5/).

The problem I am facing is on click of the links the Sammyjs config is not getting invoked.  Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
Sammy(function () {

this.get('#:section', function () {
    //this.params.section-- need to see the section selected by using this 

alert(this.params.section);//currently this is not working

    //based on the selected section would like to update the selectedSection and apply the appropriate view models

    //also a
    //ko.applyBindings(settingsModel, document.getElementById("settings"));
    //ko.applyBindings(notificationsModel, document.getElementById("notifications"));            

});
}).run();
```

Comment: You need to also add jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/TBzA5/ then your code is working fine.

Comment: thanks for identifying the error. I am kind of new here any reason why my reputation took a dip by 2.

Comment: Someone down-voted the question

Answer (score 0):

the code works fine after including jquery as per nemesv comment.
Once again thanks a lot.